# iOS: What is an audio unit?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, avaudioplayer, audiounit

Audio Unit looks like a Core audio concept, but I see that it has many custom configurations, so I'm thinking can I use audio unit's setting on an AVAudioPlayer?
but first, what is an audio unit?

Comment: Audio Units are interface services provided by the operating system to generate, process, receive, or otherwise manipulate streams of audio in near-real-time with minimal latency. For more info check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 4):

From Apple documentation:

> "*iOS provides audio processing plug-ins that support mixing, equalization, format conversion, and realtime input/output for
>   recording, playback, offline rendering, and live conversation such as
>   for VoIP (Voice over Internet Protocol). You can dynamically load and
>   use these powerful and flexible plug-ins, known as
>   **audio units***"

You can find more here:

[iOS Developer Library - Using Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6) 
[iOS Developer Library - About Audio Unit Hosting](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH1-SW1)